# Python - Matrix Generation from List

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a matrix with the following conditions:

1. Get the length of a given list.
2. For the length of that list, append an incremental integer to the front of that list.
3. Generate a matrix of these values.

The goal of this matrix would be to be able to perform look ups based on a specific position in the matrix. The incremental integers would be a 'building' and the values following are the timings to get to another building.

So for instance, looking up [0][2] in the matrix, would be 5 minutes from building 1 to building 2.

Input:

```
myList=['0 5 7 3', '4 0 3 6', '6 4 0 4', '4 5 6 0']
```

Expected Matrix:

```
1 0 5 7 3
2 4 0 3 6
3 6 4 0 4
4 4 5 6 0
```

Any thoughts for the most efficient way to do this? I tried to work through it with dictionaries, but the way I want to do access patterns of matrix[0][2], wouldn't work the way I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
myList = ['0 5 7 3', '4 0 3 6', '6 4 0 4', '4 5 6 0']

result = [[i] + [int(n) for n in s.split()] for i, s in enumerate(myList, 1)]

for row in result:
    print(*row)
```

**Output**

```
1 0 5 7 3
2 4 0 3 6
3 6 4 0 4
4 4 5 6 0
```

With this you can do:

```
print(result[0][2])
```

**Output** *(result[0][2])*

```
5
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create a list of list:

```
list_of_lists = []
for string in myList:
  string_list = string.split(' ')
  int_list = [int(x) for x in string_list]
  list_of_lists.append(int_list)
```

Second, use numpy:

```
import numpy
matrix = numpy.array(list_of_lists)
```